# how change locale in email being sent from controller - laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, locale, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am successfully sending emails with this piece of code:

```
 \App::setLocale('pl');
 Mail::send('emails.new_'.$itemtype, ['object' => $object, 'email' =>     $email_recipee], function ($m) use ( $email_recipee, $object, $itemtype) {
 $m->to($email_recipee, 'Title')->subject(' Subject of email');
 //
 });
```

But the emails are translated to `en`, the default language of the app.

### My question

How make Laravel send email with a locale declared just for a particular email (each recipient has a different language set).

#### What I tried:

- `\App::setLocale('pl');` just before the `Mail` command
- setting my working middleware in the controller globally in `__construct()`:

  `$this->middleware('setLocale'); // sets the locale to the recipee locale`

#### dirty (?) solution

For now I just add a line inside the email view:

```
{{ \App::setLocale($lead->client->lang)}}
```

Any better way to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Yep, `App::setLocale($locale)` is the way to go.

Comment: If you have `app/Mail` directory with your Emails in there, you could set that in the constructor. Unless you are still using the old way of sending emails.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: Since Laravel 5.7 you can use [localize mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#localizing-mailables):

```
Mail::to($request->user())->locale('es')->send(
    new OrderShipped($order)
);
```

---

Before Laravel 5.7:

What you proposed should work. Just change the locale before sending the mail. However you should be sure to reset the locale:

```
$temp = \App::getLocale();
\App::setLocale($user->language);
\Mail::to($user)->send(new OrderShipped($order));
\App::setLocale($temp);
```

Since this is a bit bloated you could simplify that to

```
\App\Mail\SendMail::to($user, '\App\Mail\OrderShipped', [$order]);
```

if you create the following `SendMail` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;

class SendMail
{

  /**
   * Send Mail to correct emailadress and set correct language
   * @param  User   $user
   * @param  String $classname
   * @param  Array  $data
   * @return void
   */
  public static function to(User $user, String $class, Array $params)
  {
    $temp = \App::getLocale();
    \App::setLocale($user->lang);

    $reflection_class = new \ReflectionClass($class);
    $mailclass = $reflection_class->newInstanceArgs($params);

    \Mail::to($user)->send($mailclass);

    \App::setLocale($temp);
  }
}
```

Maybe its also usefull to know that you can get your language content also without `setLocale` . For instance `__('birthday_parole', [], 'pl')` will try to give you the polish version, despite the settings of `setLocale`.

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR:** Just set a `$locale` field in an object of `Mailable` class:

```
class ResetPassword extends Mailable
{
   // ...

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, string $token)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->token = $token;
        /*
         * Set locale of mail to User's locale
         */
        $this->locale = $this->user->locale; // <-- of course adapt this line to YOUR User model :]
    }
```

**Long story:**

There is a trait `Localizable`. It declares a method `withLocale` that calls a given function "enveloped" in a specified locale. By "enveloping" I mean: remember a current locale, set a new locale, call a function, restore the remembered locale.

An example of usage can be found in `\Illuminate\Mail\Mailable::send`:

```
public function send(MailerContract $mailer)
{
    return $this->withLocale($this->locale, function () use ($mailer) {
        Container::getInstance()->call([$this, 'build']);

        return $mailer->send($this->buildView(), $this->buildViewData(), function ($message) {
            $this->buildFrom($message)
                 ->buildRecipients($message)
                 ->buildSubject($message)
                 ->runCallbacks($message)
                 ->buildAttachments($message);
        });
    });
}
```

However, this method gives us a clue how to change a locale for a **mail** - in the first line there is `$this->locale`. Indeed, `Mailable` has this field defined:

```
class Mailable implements MailableContract, Renderable
{
   // ...

    /**
     * The locale of the message.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $locale;
```

Comment: This should be marked as answer. In my opinion the most clean answer. Thank you.

Comment: I aggree with Baspa.
Plus, if you set the locale in the constructor of the mailable, it also works when you are using the Mail::to()->queue() method.

Comment: Good solution, **but** OP needs it for Laravel **5.4** (anyone tried with 5.4?).

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using Laravel 6.* and viewing this post, it looks like things have changed more recently.

Now, you can define the locale within the controller itself, simply by adding `->locale()` to the Mail.

For example:

```
Mail::to($request->user())->locale('es')->send(
    new OrderShipped($order)
);
```

For more information, please see the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#localizing-mailables).

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, I just tested your solution and it is working under Laravel 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Mailable class` [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#generating-mailables)
In the constructor `__construct(User $user)` you can type hint the user, and set the locale from there:

```
            <?php

            namespace App\Mail;

            use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
            use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
            use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
            use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
            use App\User;

            class Welcome extends Mailable
            {
                use Queueable, SerializesModels;

                protected $user;

                /**
                 * Create a new message instance.
                 *
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function __construct(User $lead)
                {
                    \App::setLocale($lead->client->lang);
                    $this->user = $lead;
                    $this->subject = trans('welcome_title');
                }

                /**
                 * Build the message.
                 *
                 * @return $this
                 */
                public function build()
                {
                    return $this->view('emails.welcome')->with('user', $this->user);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I will test it tomorrow. Sorry for the delay. 
Peter

Comment: But then you change the locale permanently right? Don't you need to switch it back?

Comment: Being in a queue worker, the mail request will terminate with that specific locale but it won't affect the original request.

Comment: For me, all I had to add was: \App::setLocale(strtolower($leads->page)); within NewLead.php